# Execution not starting in node desktop when i am using Selenium GRID

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

Execution not starting in node desktop when I am using Selenium GRID. Here I tried to launch Firefox browser in node desktop. How can I solve this issue? Your answers could be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
   **Below is my code**

    public class GridExample {
        WebDriver driver;
        String baseUrl,nodeUrl;

        @BeforeTest
        public void setup() throws MalformedURLException{
            baseUrl="https://www.google.com/ncr";
            nodeUrl="http://**.0.0.*:5566/wd/hub";  
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D://krishna//geckodriver-v0.11.1-win32//geckodriver.exe");
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setBrowserName("firefox");
            capabilities.setPlatform(Platform.VISTA);
            driver=new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(nodeUrl),capabilities);
        }

        @Test
        public void sampleTest() throws InterruptedException{
            driver.get(baseUrl);
            Thread.sleep(10000); //slow down for demo purposes
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
            element.sendKeys("webdriver");
            element.submit();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }

        @AfterTest
        public void teardown(){
            driver.close();
        }
    }

    **Below is my output stacktrace**
```

> Jun 09, 2017 5:35:55 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's
>   Law holds true on the remote end log4j:WARN No appenders could be
>   found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. log4j:WARN See
>   http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
>
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest setup
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
>   start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: 'unknown',
>   revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' System info:
>   host: 'SYSTEM26-PC', ip: '10.0.0.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
>
> ```
>  SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest tear down SKIPPED: sampleTest org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
> ```
>
> start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: 'unknown',
>   revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:43:45 -0700' System info:
>   host: 'SYSTEM26-PC', ip: '10.0.0.14', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch:
>   'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
>
> ===============================================
>       Default test
>       Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
>
> ## Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
>
> =============================================== Default suite Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1 Configuration Failures: 1, Skips:
>
> ## 1

Comment: Anybody please help me...

Comment: There's very little information here to start debugging. Please include the version numbers of browser and selenium

Comment: Selenium version 3.0 and Firefox version 53.0.3

Comment: Is that the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: Hi Mahadevan, I added my complete stacktrace above

Comment: Just to rule out issues with geckodriver+FF combinations can you please try running this curl command and post back the results ? `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"capabilities":{"browserName":"firefox"}}' http://localhost:4444/session`

Comment: I didn't get clearly what you are saying

Comment: Please run that curl command on your desktop and share the results. The expected result is that you should be able to see a Firefox browser open up in your machine. If you dont have curl installed you can make use of the POSTMAN Chrome plugin to do this as well.

Comment: Thank you Mahadevan

Comment: please let me know what was the outcome.

Comment: Which add-on can i add, Postman Interceptor or Postman? in my chrome

Comment: I think it should be [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).

Comment: I added the Postman add-on to chrome. How can i launch the Postman Chrome? Is there any separate procedure?

Comment: Please refer [here](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/31/tip-how-to-launch-postman-really-quickly/)